# get UTC date using moment in javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs, utc

I am getting a utc date using `utcDate = moment.utc(new Date()).format()`. But this `utcDate` is a string, not Date object. By using `new Date(utcDate)`,it is again converting utc date lo my local date. Please help me in getting utc date object. 
I work in javascript.

`utcDate = moment.utc(new Date()).toDate()` is converting it to my local date `Sun Sep 01 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Comment: Can you please share the utcDate string ?

Comment: ```2019-09-01T00:00:00Z```

Comment: I have edited the answer for moment.js solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using moment.js**

```
var date = moment();
console.log(date.format()) // 2019-08-30T11:08:27+05:30

date = moment().utc();
console.log(date.format()); // 2019-08-30T05:38:27Z
```

**Using Javascript**

```
var dateObject = new Date();
dateObject.toLocaleString()
"8/30/2019, 10:55:19 AM" // My current time

var utcDateObject = new Date( dateObject.getUTCFullYear(), dateObject.getUTCMonth(), dateObject.getUTCDate(), dateObject.getUTCHours(), dateObject.getUTCMinutes(), dateObject.getUTCSeconds() );
utcDateObject.toLocaleString()
"8/30/2019, 5:26:04 AM" // UTC time which is 5.5 hours less than my local time
```

Comment: by using ```toUTCString``` will give string as output. but I want date object

Comment: I have edited my answer again. Please check the first way. Most probably that is something you are looking for. Let me know if you are still facing any problem.

Comment: @ManishMenaria Works for me. Thanks!!